# Embed links in Firebase text for ionic app

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, firebase, ionic3

I am developing an ionic app and the content is stored in Firebase. How to embed links in text?

For example, This is how the Firebase JSON file looks like

```
"OtherActivities" : {
  "Food Truck Mania" : {
    "badgecolor" : "",
    "badgetext" : "",
    "enddate" : [ 2018, 8, 24, 21, 0, 0, 0 ],
    "icon" : "ios-restaurant",
    "id" : 5,
    "image" : "",
    "location" : "Behind  Aula in front of the library",
    "map" : [ 99, 99],
    "paragraph1" : "There are a variety of food trucks available for lunch, dinner, and snacks or drinks in between. Take a break from your day and share a bite with friends. ",
    "paragraph2" : "",
    "paragraph3" : "",
    "startdate" : [ 2018, 8, 24, 12, 0, 0, 0 ],
    "time" : "12:00 - 21:00",
    "title" : "Food Truck Mania",
    "website" : ""
  }, ...
```

Now, say I want to embed a link (google.com) to "food trucks" so that users can click on food trucks and be redirected to google.com. How to do that? I am finding it particularly tricky to implement since i am reading the paragraph contents inside `<p> .. </p>` in the respective HTML file.